# Comparable as argument in Java

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I have a class PriorityList with the signature

```
Tree<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
```

(which is given, I can't modify). The elements `Tree` are inserted in some order, given the key (i.e. it considers the key's `compareTo` method).

Let's say I have `Tree<Integer, Integer>`. The default `compareTo` of integer considers ascending order. I would like to be able to somehow have `Tree` insert the elements in descending order, if I wanted to. I know I could probably write another class `MyInteger` which implements `Comparable` and has a `compareTo` on its own.

But is there another way? What I would really like is to be able to somehow tell the `Tree` how to order the values.

Second question: If I were able to modify `Tree`, how would one pass a comparator as argument? (keeping generic types-syntax in mind).

Comment: You can multiply the `Integer` times `-1`

Comment: Impossible to answer without any code or documentation of your `Tree` class.

Answer (score 2):

You've named the two ways to do it: pass in a comparator or have key be comparable.  If the class doesn't let you pass in your own comparator, then you're stuck monkeying with the keys or creating your own subclass with the Comparable interface

The alternative code would look something like this.

```
public class Tree<K,V>{
   public Tree( Comparator<K> cmp ) {...}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to create a new class for reverse. you can use [Collections.reverseOrder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) to obtain a `Comparator` in reverse of a given one.

As for the second question, you will simply add a setter to your tree. Something like:  `setComparator(Comparator<Key> c)` and then use that comparator for all the comparisons needed in your `Tree`.